# Script to retrieve whole dictionary after matching pattern of a value contained in the dictionary

Tags: bash, shell

I have dictionaries like these in an xml file:

```sh
<key>Key1</key>
<dict>
      <key>ChildKey1</key>
      <array>
             <string>String1</string>
             <string>String2</string>
      </array>
      <key>ChildKey2</key>
      <string>String3</string>
      <key>ChildKey3</key>
      <string>ABC</string>
</dict>

<key>Key2</key>
<dict>
      <key>ChildKey1</key>
      <array>
             <string>String1</string>
             <string>String2</string>
      </array>
      <key>ChildKey2</key>
      <string>String3</string>
      <key>ChildKey3</key>
      <string>DEF</string>
</dict>
```

I need a script to the search for a matching pattern. Once the match is found I need to retrieve the whole dictionary in which the matching value is present.

For (eg):
If the matching pattern I am searching for is ABC, then I need to retrieve the whole dictionary under Key1.

I tried using Grep but Couldnt able to retrieve the whole dictionary

Comment: No grep, use xml aware tooling. Ex. `xmllint`.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with shell or bash scripting?

Comment: There is. Will there __always__ be an empty line between keys? You need to split your input into chunks of key+dict, for starters. Then you can regex into chunks with `<dict>.*<string>ABC</string></dict>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use XMLLint to select data based on XPath :

```
xmllint --xpath '//dict[.//string/text() = "ABC"]' your_xml_file
```

This will select every `dict` node that contains a `string` node whose text content is `ABC`.

If the text to look for can be found in other nodes than `string` ones you can use a wildcard :

```
xmllint --xpath '//dict[.//*/text() = "ABC"]' your_xml_file
```

To improve performances you should use a more precise path than the `//dict` recursive descent I used since I didn't know your whole XML structure.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with shell or bash scripting?

Comment: Pure bash? Might be possible, but it's certain to be more troublesome than it's worth. Bash + utilities? Well that's what my answer is. xmllint is included in the libxml2 library which is widely available on linux systems